# Compound IF statement it Javascript, Function not returning the value

Tags: javascript

Compound IF statement it Javascript, Function not returning the value.  I cant find the syntax error, but I am pretty sure it is a simple one.  This was used as an example in class and it ran there, I was tasked to make some modifications and now it wont run correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Credit Card Payment</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcPay(paybill)
{
  yourPay = 0;
  if (paybill.paytype[0].checked == true)
  {
    yourPay = (yourPay + 50);
  }
  else
  {
    yourPay = (yourPay + 0);
  }
}
if (paybill.medtype[0].checked == true)
{
  yourPay = (yourPay + (bal.value * .10));
}
else
{
  if (paybill.medtype[1].checked == true)
  {
    yourPay = yourPay + bal.value;
  }
  else
  {
    yourPay = yourPay + otherP.value;
  }
}
yourPay = Math.round(yourPay*100)/100;
return yourPay;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Calc Pay</h1>
<form name="paybill">
<p>Enter name:
<input type = "text" name="payname"></p>
Credit Card Number: 
<input type = "text" name="cardNo"></p>
<p>Account Balance: <input type = "text" name="bal">
<p>Enter type:<br />

<input type = "radio" name="paytype" value="salary">Late Payment<br />
<input type = "radio" name="paytype" value="hourly">Prior to Due Date</p>
</p>
<p>Enter Desired Payment Type:<br />
<input type = "radio" name="medtype">Minimum Payment<br />
<input type = "radio" name="medtype">Pay Balance<br />
<input type = "radio" name="medtype">Other Amount: <input type = "text" 

name="otherP"></p>

<input type="button" value="Calculate your payment" onclick="pay.value=calcPay

(paybill)" />
<b><i>Your payment is:</i></b> <input type="text" name="pay" size="10" /><be />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/myrvvxcj/1/

Comment: This code is completely unreadable without proper indentation of all your if/else blocks and, in fact, if you do proper indentation, it will be easy to see where your errors are.

Comment: You have two extra `}`, one after the end of each `else { }` block. *edit*, sorry, just one. The first one. INDENT CODE CAREFULLY!

Comment: After fixing your indentation, it should be obvious what the issue is.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/myrvvxcj/3/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calcPay(paybill)
        {
             var yourPay = 0; // first declare yourPay.

            if (!!paybill.paytype[0].checked)
            {
                yourPay = (yourPay + 50);
            }


        if (!!paybill.medtype[0].checked)
        {
            yourPay = (yourPay + (paybill.bal.value * .10)); //bill is part of paybill
        }
        else
        {
            if (!!paybill.medtype[1].checked)
            {
                yourPay = yourPay + paybill.bal.value; //bill is part of paybill
            }
            else
            {
                yourPay = yourPay + paybill.otherP.value;//otherP is part of paybill
            }
        }
            yourPay = Math.round(yourPay*100)/100;
            return yourPay;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: if `checked` is true or false, you don't need to use `!!` to convert to boolean. it already is.

Comment: Thanks Ankit, I got it function.

Answer (score 0):

If you align your tabs properly, it's easy to see where the error is.

```
function calcPay(paybill)
{
    yourPay = 0;
    if (paybill.paytype[0].checked == true)
    {
        yourPay = (yourPay + 50);
    }
    else
    {
        yourPay = (yourPay + 0);
    }
} // < This should not be here!
    if (paybill.medtype[0].checked == true)
    {
        yourPay = (yourPay + (bal.value * .10));
    }
    else
    {
        if (paybill.medtype[1].checked == true)
        {
            yourPay = yourPay + bal.value;
        }
        else
        {
            yourPay = yourPay + otherP.value;
        }
    }
    yourPay = Math.round(yourPay*100)/100;
    return yourPay;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5oh6533L/1/

```
function calcPay (paybill) {
  var yourPay = 0;

  if (paybill.paytype[0].checked) {
    yourPay += 50);
  } 

  // this does nothing
  // else yourPay = (yourPay + 0);

  if (paybill.medtype[0].checked) {
    yourPay += (bal.value * .10);
  } 

  else if (paybill.medtype[1].checked) {
    yourPay += bal.value;
  } 

  else yourPay += otherP.value;

  return Math.round(yourPay * 100) / 100;
}
```